# Verifying the divergence theorem over B

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, divergence-theorem

This is the exercise:

> Let $B$ be the region of $\mathbb{R}^3$
> $$B = {(x,y,z) | x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1,\ z^2\geq x^2+y^2}$$  and and be the field $$\mathbf{F}(x,y,z) = (x,y,z)$$

My guess was since we are dealing with a hyperbole (top part) and a sphere, use spherical coordinates for the triple integral, and for the other part of the theorem use spherical for the sphere and cylindric for the upper cone.

the triple integral, I integrate 3, which is the result of the divergence of F with $0\leq \theta\leq2\pi$;$0\leq\phi\leq1\pi/4$ and $0\leq\rho\leq1$ but it didn't work, results are weird and for the other part of the theorem the sum of the double integrals did not give me as the triple integral.

Sorry about my english, is so bad.

Comment: This region has two components: one for $z>0$ and one for $z<0$. Are we supposed to only be considering one of them? Also the boundaries here are a sphere and a cone, not a sphere and a hyperbola.

Comment: @eyeballfrog yes, just the $$z>0$$

Comment: Your method for the integral of the divergence seems correct. Perhaps something went wrong with the surface integral.

Comment: Yes, also thought that, for surface I divided it into two problems, the 'cone' and the sphere, for the sphere the normal in spherical coordinates was $$n = (-cos(\theta)*sin(\phi)^2 ,sin(\phi)^2*sin(\theta),-sin(\phi)*cos(\theta))$$, scalarly multiplied with the field the integrated with $0<=\theta<=2\pi$;$0<=\phi<=1\pi/4$

Comment: The surface normal of a sphere is $\hat{r} = (\sin\phi\cos\theta, \sin\phi\sin\theta,\cos\phi)$. Dotting that with $F$ should give 1.

Comment: How did you get the normal like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The divergence theorem in spherical coordinates gives
$$\begin{align}
\iiint_D \text{div}(\mathbf{F})dxdydz&=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\phi=0}^{\pi/4}\int_{\rho=0}^1 3\rho^2\sin(\phi) d\rho  d\phi d\theta\\
&=2\pi\cdot 3[\rho^3/3]_0^1[-\cos(\phi)]_{\phi=0}^{\pi/4}=2\pi\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right).
\end{align}$$
On the other hand, the flux through the conic surface is zero  because $\mathbf{n}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{F}$ whereas the flux through the spherical cap is
$$\iint_S \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S}=|S|=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\phi=0}^{\pi/4}\sin(\phi) d\phi d\theta=2\pi\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right).$$
because $\mathbf{n}=\mathbf{F}$ (the sphere has radius 1).

Comment: Great, but didn't get how the normal dotting the field is just $sin(\phi)$

Comment: @HaitianSpaceman The infinitesimal element of area in spherical coordinates is $r^2\sin(\phi)$ and here $r=1$.